# problem with qt for symiban none-english project name

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

how can i create a qt project with none-english name.or how can i deploy the application on to device with a none-english application name,like chinese or japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolchain supports e.g. UTF-8 encoding. Just save your non-ASCII files as UTF-8 and you should be all right.